# Pack python library to one file

Tags: python, pack

I want to pack pure python library into one source python script. (not exe, app, etc. I need exactly lib.py file) Is it possible? Which tools are exist for this?

Comment: Do you mean you have several *.py files and want to combine them all to one? Yes, that is possible. However, requests for tools to do that are off-topic here.

Comment: such as `zipimport`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html

Comment: Why don't you just store them in a .py file? What are you going to be doing with the .py file?

Comment: It is an off-topic unfortunately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Yep. I have many structured python scripts. (In my case the library is sympy, but nevermind.) And I looking for a tool that can make (automatic) one source file from all sources of library

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, I must send somewhere only one source. This is hard limitation.
I want use third-party library, but i cant install required package on the destination system. So i asking - how to include whole library to my source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is to pack all your python files into a zip: https://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/05/21/python-zip-files/

If you really want to, sure, it is possible to pack everything (including a zip I think) to a .py file, just write your custom importhook, store base64-encoded zip archive as a string in your since python source, a bit of hardcore magic here and there and voila, single python program,

Alternatively you could refactor all your dependencies and include these as classes for example in your source, but why bother?

Finally, there's no simple way to include compiled dependencies, i.e. those `.so / .dylib / .dll` files.

I don't think there is a tool out there that does exactly what you want, but I reckon pyinstaller/py2exe can be used to get pretty close, for example http://www.py2exe.org/old/ look for `library.zip`.

Comment: I think putting all the files into a zip file is a good option. Python has a zipimporter which is able to import from zip files. https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html