# Python: include module into one *.py file

Tags: python, module

I have directory with python module, which contains `__init__.py`, some other `*.py` files and directories with `*.py` and `__init__.py` files. How can I include this module into my program's .py file, which use it? I need to distribute only one *.py file, which must include this module and my code, which uses module.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to distribute only one *.py file?  You could use distutils to package multiple files in to a single distributable installable with easy_install/pip instead, which would be a better choice than a gigantic concatenated block of python in a single file.  You'll also almost certainly run in to name collisions and other problems if you try to directly merge multiple modules in to a single namespace.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426211/pack-python-library-to-one-file#comment35901196_23426211

Comment: @user2160982 You should answer the comments if you want to get further help. Tell us for example why they work/do not work for you.